# To understand, consolidate & reduce the shown disk space taken up by iTunes & iphone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, applications, backup, podcasts

### Consolidating iTunes

As per the link quoted below:

- iTunes content & data was spread over 2 folders as versions upgraded, but never consolidated.
- Hence, the 'same' separate folders in both:

  - Mobile Applications
  - Voice Memos

**Any way to consolidate them under the newer single path?**

---

**C:\Users\MyUserName\iTunes\..**

- Also, key information & mappings seem to be present in: `iTunes Music Library.xml`

**..\iTunes Media**

- ..\iTunes Media\Mobile Applications: 25.9 GB
- ..\iTunes Media\Voice Memos: 1.3 GB

**..\iTunes Music**

- ..\iTunes Music\Mobile Applications: 4.4 GB
- ..\iTunes Music\Voice Memos: 237 MB
- ..\iTunes Music\Music: 100 MB
- ..\iTunes Music\Books: 50 MB
- ..\iTunes Music\Podcasts: 5.9 GB

---

[Q. Where does iTunes store its podcast files on the computer? I would like to manually back up my collection to an external drive.](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/05/01/technology/personaltech/how-to-back-up-itunes-podcasts.html)

> A.
>
> - Start with the `Music` or `My Music` library on the PC or Mac.
> - Inside your `Music library`, you should see an iTunes folder and inside that,
>
>   - there should be an `iTunes Media` folder — unless it has been purposely moved. Podcasts are kept in the `iTunes Media` folder by
>       default.
>   - (If you have been using iTunes for years or haven’t upgraded to iTunes 9 or a later version, the folder may be called `iTunes Music`
>       instead of iTunes Media.)

---

### Overlaps/ Duplication between iTunes & Backup

Given that iTunes syncs/ backs up the iPhone (mostly apps) there has to be some overlap/ redundancy between the below mentioned `Backup` folder & above mentioned folders.

---

C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\

- ..\Mobile Sync\Backup: 20.8 GB

But so far, duplicate file finders I've run can't find any.

---

Besides just asking me to delete stuff, what are your thoughts on understanding, consolidating & harmonizing these set of folders, towards decreasing the disk footprint.

This disk tree map was taken using [SpaceSniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/) and parts of it blurred for privacy. But it shows big chunks of space taken up :

[image]

Comment: What's the path difference between the 4.4. GB MA folder and the 25.9 GB MA folder? Have you consolidated the library after making a backup of the PC? That typically harmonizes all files if you let iTunes keep things organized.

Comment: @bmike - ..iTunes Media\Mobile Applications: 25.9 GB v/s 
..iTunes Music\Mobile Applications: 4.4 GB - How can I consolidate/ harmonize both folders? How do I make iTunes do it? I dont think it can

Comment: The full path doesn't have .. you are showing the end of the path which doesn't help us help you.

Comment: @bmike - The full path is obviously visibly clear in the DiskMap from C:\ Please have a look. Its not some unusual path. The typical path: C:\users\myname\AppData\etc...

Comment: Sorry - there's nothing clear in that image to me. But, I'm used to different OS and different visualization tools. If you edit the post explicitly, someone might have an answer. Your call if you feel that's worth your effort - there are 16 other eyes that have seen the post - perhaps in time someone will have a better solution.

Comment: @bmike - The image might seem a bit fuzzy as it doesnt fit on SE. If you Click it.. it Zooms in and will show you structure clearly.

Comment: @bmike - added more information & clarity

Answer (score 1):

In iTunes prefs > sync (or devices) there is an option to delete old iOS Backups.

Comment: Old backups have been deleted already. All this is currently synced & backed up stuff